# Why would this AWS lambda cause error: WARNING: Callback/response already delivered

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

- I created an API Gateway + lambda for `signUp` with `amazon-cognito-identity-js`.
- Then I implemented a Cognito trigger function for preSignUp with Typescript

I use Serverless framework to pack and deploy. The runtime is Node 12

+++++++

```
  const wrapperHandler: Handler<CognitoUserPoolEvent> = async (
    event,
    context,
    callback
  ) => {
    let error = null;

    try {
      await myAsyncFunc();
    } catch (e) {
      error = e;
    }

    callback(error, event);
  };
```

Everything works fine, it can return the error to the actual endpoint lambda which will then be returned, if no error, the logic will be executed.

However, this warning is pretty annoying.

The code is for `preSignUp` in CloudWatch

> WARNING: Callback/response already delivered.  Did your function invoke the callback and also return a promise? For more details, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

In the code, I didn't return anything before calling the callback, why would this happen? and how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your error message what did you get, you are mixing callback style with `async/await` style, then it throws a warning.

I prefer use `async/await`. This mean, handler function always is a async function (with async keyword), then instead of call `callback` function, just return the result, and you no need `callback` parameter in handler function.

In error case, just throw the error (without `try/catch` block).

```
const wrapperHandler: Handler<CognitoUserPoolEvent> = async (
  event,
  context,
  // callback
) => {
  // let error = null;

  try {
    await myAsyncFunc();
  } catch (e) {
    // error = e;
    // Do something  with your error
    throw e;
  }

  // callback(error, event);
  return event; // just return result for handler function
};
```

In simple:

```
const wrapperHandler: Handler<CognitoUserPoolEvent> = async (
  event,
  context,
) => {
  await myAsyncFunc();

  return event;
};
```